# кеш(сессии) в android прлиожении на html/css/javascript

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

Разрабатываю тестовое приложение на android и из опыта в веб программировании задумался о таком понятии как сессии, тоесть не регистрируясь в БД нас наш браузер распознает и эта сессия длится какоето время.

И хотелось задать вопрос о том, как это реализуется в android приложениях - тоесть мы не регистрируясь скачав приложение делаем там изменения и оно нас помнит пока мы его не сотрем. Посоветуйте ключевые понятия или слова, в какую сторону копать.

Comment: Куки, копайте в их сторону. Если интересует хранение настроек на стороне клиента то это очевидный SharedPreferences

Comment: Непонятно, кто что помнит, и кто что после стирает. Приведите пример

Comment: @metalurgus, в андроид приложениях часто бывает такое - мы качаем приложения, даже если взять игру любую, проходим уровни - выключаем устройство и уровни нами пройденные, они сохранены пока мы не удалим приложение. Даже просто наш лучший результат. Щас остановился на  localStorage, но не уверен что подойдет и будет хранить массив со значениями до удаления приложения.

Comment: Preference, в крайнем случае - БД, если речь идет о хранении на стороне клиента

Comment: @Ni55aN, в крайнем - это да) ну а если иметь оффлайн приложение...

Comment: БД - не имеется в виду на стороне сервера, в Android'ах также в каждом приложении можно создать свою БД

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас есть несколько **кросс-платформенных** способов сохранить информацию локально на устройстве.

Кукис работают в `cordova` плохо и вообще устаревшая технология. Лучше посмотрите на `localStorage` - современная замена для кукис, ее легко использовать, хранится на устройстве вечно (т.е. до обнуления данных приложения в настройках или де-инсталляции):

```
//записали
window.localStorage.setItem('user_id', 'CVB765');
window.localStorage['user_email'] = 'bobm@acme.com';

//прочитали
var userID = window.localStorage.getItem('user_id');
var userEmail = window.localStorage['user_email'];
```

Есть еще `WebSQL`, локальная база данных, все плюшки работы с базой данных, знакомый язык запросов, выборки, индексы и прочее:

```
//открываем
var db     = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'Test DB', 2 * 1024 * 1024),
    msg    = '',
    status = document.getElementById('status');


//записываем 
db.transaction(function (tx) {
   tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LOGS (id unique, log)');
   tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO LOGS (id, log) VALUES (1, "Log entry 1")');
   tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO LOGS (id, log) VALUES (2, "Log entry 2")');
   msg = '<p>Log message created and row inserted.</p>';
   status.innerHTML =  msg;
 });

//читаем
db.transaction(function (tx) {
  tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM LOGS', [], function (tx, results) {
   var len = results.rows.length, i;
   msg = "<p>Found rows: " + len + "</p>";
   status.innerHTML +=  msg;
   for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
     msg = "<p><b>" + results.rows.item(i).log + "</b></p>";
     status.innerHTML +=  msg;
   }
 }, null);
});
```

Примерно так же работает SQlite, но т.к. это имплементация SQL на C, для ее использования [нужен этот плагин](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage).

Ну и наконец, вы можете [сохранять и читать файлы в файловой системе через File API plugin](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html). В iOS они, предполагаю, останутся в песочнице и будут удалены вместе с приложением, а на Android они останутся в системе даже после удаления приложения. Конечно, это если вашему приложению эту привилегию даст пользователь.

Что касается упомянутых тут Shared Preferences, то это чисто андроидная фишка. На iOS это работает иначе, на WinPhone - еще более иначе. [Есть плагины](https://github.com/apla/me.apla.cordova.app-preferences), которые позволяют кросс-платформенно писать-читать эти преференции, но я бы на них не полагался, это все-таки маргинальный подход, в отличие от популярных и нативных, которые я описал выше.